# How to reduce spaces between buttons in MDC-Android

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-layout, user-interface

I am learning to create UI in XML now, and I'm struggling with such a problem.

I create UI which looks like this: [UI in Android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gen02.png)

And on the phone it looks like this: [How it looks in reality (screenshot from a phone)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kvshA.png)

How to reduce these vertical spaces?
I want to get rid of this: [These marked spaces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kCFxG.png)

This is LinearLayout, and these are much bigger than I want them to be.

Here's my XML code for this UI:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp">


    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="101dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:paddingTop="16dp"
                android:text="Yooooo"
                android:textAlignment="textEnd"
                android:textSize="50sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <Button
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:textColor="@color/md_theme_dark_error"
                android:text="CLEAR ALL"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/md_theme_dark_onPrimary"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="20sp"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/md_theme_dark_onPrimary"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="/"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/md_theme_dark_primary"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/md_theme_dark_onPrimary"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="*"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/md_theme_dark_primary"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/md_theme_dark_onPrimary"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="+"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/md_theme_dark_primary"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/md_theme_dark_onPrimary"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="-"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/md_theme_dark_primary"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/md_theme_dark_onPrimary"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="="
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/md_theme_dark_primary"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/md_theme_dark_onPrimary"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="7"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/md_theme_dark_onPrimary"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="8"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_marginTop="1dp"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/md_theme_dark_onPrimary"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="9"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_marginTop="1dp"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="245dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/md_theme_dark_onPrimary"
                android:text="4"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_marginTop="1dp"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/md_theme_dark_onPrimary"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="5"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_marginTop="1dp"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/md_theme_dark_onPrimary"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="6"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_marginTop="1dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="265dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <Button
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/md_theme_dark_onPrimary"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="1"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_marginTop="1dp"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/md_theme_dark_onPrimary"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="2"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_marginTop="1dp"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/md_theme_dark_onPrimary"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="6"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_marginTop="1dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Thanks very much for every helpful hint/answer!!!

I tried changing the weight, reducing DPI spaces, and setting the android:layout_marginTop/Bottom to 10 dpi, I thought it would stop it from increasing the spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reduce the `layout_height` property for the `Linear Layout` and for the `Button` .
And as an advice if you want to learn UI creation using XML just try playing around with the editor and test different things it will be much easier to learn & memorise this way.

Comment: It helped, I changed every layout_height to wrap_content intead of dpi height, and it worked. And I also added some padding that buttons on Tablet View will not stick to each other. Thanks very much bro!